# Facebook permission alert shows repeated text

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am fetching the FB user list from settings with the basic profile and friend's list permission. It works fine. But the alert shows the text as follows:

"App name" would like to access your basic profile info and list of friends on your behalf. In addition, it would like to access your basic profile info and list of friends."

Is anything wrong with the code?

```
    ACAccountType *FBaccountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

NSString *key = FACEBOOK_APP_ID;

NSMutableDictionary *dictFB  = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:key,ACFacebookAppIdKey,@[@"email", @"user_friends", @"public_profile"],ACFacebookPermissionsKey, nil];

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:FBaccountType options:dictFB completion:
 ^(BOOL granted, NSError *e)
 {
     if (granted)
     {
         self.facebookAcconts = [[accountStore accountsWithAccountType:FBaccountType]mutableCopy];

         if (self.facebookAcconts.count > 0)
         {
             id account = [self.facebookAcconts objectAtIndex:0];
             if (account)
             {
                 [accountStore renewCredentialsForAccount:account completion:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult renewResult, NSError *error) {
                     if(!error)
                     {
                         switch (renewResult) {
                             case ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRenewed:

                                 break;
                             case ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRejected:
                                 NSLog(@"User declined permission");
                                 break;
                             case ACAccountCredentialRenewResultFailed:
                                 NSLog(@"non-user-initiated cancel, you may attempt to retry");
                                 break;
                             default:
                                 break;
                         }
                     }
                     else{
                         //handle error gracefully
                         NSLog(@"error from renew credentials%@",error);
                     }
                 }];
             }
         }
     }
 }];
```

Comment: where you called this code

Comment: I m calling this code at the sign up screen.

Comment: can you show that code

Comment: I attached the code. The code is called once I click sign up button after I enter into the code.

Comment: OMG! The indent is real. Refactor that out to different functions. More than a couple of indents is not good.